# How can I change a GridView's ItemsPanelTemplate when rotating the device?

Tags: xaml, gridview, windows-runtime

I have a GridView with an ItemsStackPanel that I would like to change the orientation on when the device is rotated.  For example, if the ItemsPanelTemplate is defined as so:

```
<GridView.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <ItemsStackPanel GroupPadding="0,0,70,0" Orientation="Horizontal"/>
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</GridView.ItemsPanel>
```

I would like to programmatically turn it into this:

```
<GridView.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <ItemsStackPanel GroupPadding="0,0,70,0" Orientation="Vertical"/>
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</GridView.ItemsPanel>
```

I can't figure out how to access this object directly.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to create two views that you want to use. Take a look at the "Grid App" template provided with Visual Studio 2012. It has a GridView and a ListView. When the devices is snapped hides the GridView and shows the ListView via a VisualState